# Change organizer in all appointments in MS CRM

Tags: collections, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I'm trying to change the organizer in the appointments with a plugin.
I have a hash table to match the guids that oughts to be replaced with the new ones.
I have a fallback user that I can use when there is no match

```
if (entity.Attributes.Contains("organizer"))
{
    var organizers = (EntityCollection)entity["organizer"];

    var record = (Entity)organizers.Entities[0];

    var organizer = (EntityReference)record["partyid"];
    // create activity party record
    Entity activityParty = new Entity();
    activityParty.LogicalName = "activityparty";

    EntityCollection colAP = new EntityCollection();
    colAP.Entities.Add(activityParty);


    if (guidHash.ContainsKey(organizer.Id.ToString()))
    {
        activityParty.Attributes["partyid"] = new EntityReference("systemuser", new Guid(guidHash[organizer.Id.ToString()]));
    }
    else
    {
        activityParty.Attributes["partyid"] = new EntityReference("systemuser", new Guid(migrationUserGuid));
    }
    entity.Attributes["organizer"] = new EntityCollection();
    entity.Attributes["organizer"] = colAP;
}
```

I registered the plugin on the pre operation step, but nothing happens, the user is still the old one.

Am I doing something wrong with the way I set the EntityCollection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the plugin is called and the guids are correct, you need to use an array of `Entity` instead `EntityCollection`:

```
if (entity.Attributes.Contains("organizer"))
{
    var organizers = (EntityCollection)entity["organizer"];
    Entity record = organizers.Entities[0];
    EntityReference organizer = (EntityReference)record["partyid"];

    // create activity party record
    Entity activityParty = new Entity(activityparty");

    if (guidHash.ContainsKey(organizer.Id.ToString()))
    {
        activityParty["partyid"] = new EntityReference("systemuser", new Guid(guidHash[organizer.Id.ToString()]));
    }
    else
    {
        activityParty["partyid"] = new EntityReference("systemuser", new Guid(migrationUserGuid));
    }
    entity["organizer"] = new Entity[] { activityParty };
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, as always. Thanks Guido!